# Resgate 2 arrays com angularjs

Tags: php, array, angularjs

query angular

```
app.controller('recipedetails', function($rootScope, $routeParams, $http)
{
 $http.get('app/querys/receita_item.php?id='+$routeParams.id).success(function(data) {
  $rootScope.recipedetails = data;
  console.log(data);
 });
});
```

Arrays receita_item.php

```
[{"id":"9","id_produto":"1","forma":"Alface","valor":"1.00","id_lanche":"3","qtd_max":"1"}]
[{"id":"41","name":"dd","value":""},{"id":"42","name":"dd","value":""}]
```

preciso desses arrays separados

```
$rootScope.recipedetails_one = data1; // [{"id":"9","id_produto":"1","forma":"Alface","valor":"1.00","id_lanche":"3","qtd_max":"1"}]

$rootScope.recipedetails_two = data2; // [{"id":"41","name":"dd","value":""},{"id":"42","name":"dd","value":""}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso ficaria assim :

```
[
 [{"id":"9","id_produto":"1","forma":"Alface","valor":"1.00","id_lanche":"3","qtd‌​_max":"1"}], [{"id":"41","name":"dd","value":""}],
 [{"id":"42","name":"dd","value":""}] 
]
```

http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-formato-json/25275

Se não for isso me desculpe, abraços.

Comment: ixi mano precisava desses array separados... pq essas listas sao diferentes

Comment: Hum. Mas isso não é possível. Ou você faz 2 consultas ou busca uma lista(coleção).

Lá no success tu pode varrer essa lista para separar os dados. por exemplo : 

data[0] - para acessar a primeira
data[1] - para acessar a segunda

.Ou fazer um forEach para varrer.

Comment: humm mais 2 busca aumenta o tempo de carregamento da pagina... e quando ponhe [0] [1] nao pega o primeiro array e nem o segundo pega o primeiro item do primeiro array e assim por diante

Comment: e na verdade quando tem 2 array [{}] ele da erro no script angular

Comment: Complicado... Faço isso frequentemente. Tenta assim: 

[
        [{"id":"9","id_produto":"1","forma":"Alface","valor":"1.00","id_lanche":"3","qtd_max":"1"}],

        [{"id":"41","name":"dd","value":""}],

        [{"id":"42","name":"dd","value":""}]
    ]

Comment: deu erro: Unexpected token ,

Comment: humm agora foi :D funcionou

Comment: Muito bom! Abração.

Comment: Obrigado @Vinícius!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a opção params do método $http.

```
app.controller('recipedetails', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
   $http({

       url: "app/querys/receita_item.php", 
       method: "GET",
       params: {id: $scope.id}

   }).success(function(data, status) {

       $scope.recipedetails = data;

   }).;  
}]);
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#get

Comment: cara meu codigo puxa correto os dados mais apenas pra 1 array como tem 2 ele nao busca...

Comment: cara meu codigo puxa os dados normal o problema e que tem 2 array na mesma pagina.. ai não responde o data

Comment: A solução então é fazer uma lista de objetos, onde você vai colocar seus 2 objetos JSON. Sendo assim vai vir os 2 no mesmo objeto. Entendeu ?

Comment: humm nao, no caso multi dimensionar esse array?

Comment: Tive que postar outra resposta para lhe mostrar o código. Creio que seu problema seja apenas organização do objeto. Dá uma olhadinha sobre listas de objetos. Valeu